# Creating dict from file with repeated row names

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `.txt` file with values like so:

```
1 3 4
2 5 6
5 7
```

I want to create a dictionary like so:

```
1 [3, 4]
2 [5, 6]
5 [7]
```

The first number in a line is the key and the rest of the line are the values to be put into the list.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?
I know the way to iterate using

```
f = open('data.txt','r')
for i in f:
```

And then using condition to create a list and then add this to the dict. But I want a neater way to do it.

Comment: what's not neat about parsing the text file and updating your dictionary as you go along? Sure you could read the whole file in, splitlines it then use a dictionary comprehension to do it, but it's up to the coder's preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict),

```
import collections 

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('data.txt','r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        l = map(int, line.strip().split())
        d[l[0]].extend(l[1:])

print(d)
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6], 5: [7]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another, more direct, way to do it:

```
d = {}
with open('somedata.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers = map(int, line.split())
        numbers = list(numbers) # for Python 3
        d.setdefault(numbers[0], []).extend(numbers[1:])

print(d)  # -> {1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6], 5: [7]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split each line into a (key, values) pair, and add them to a default dict with empty list as initial value

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)

for line in f.readlines():
    line = [int(item) for item in line.split()]
    key, *values = line
    mydict[key].extend(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option without any imports and converts the entries to ints:

```
testDict = {}

with open('test.txt') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   for line in lines:
      line = map(int, line.split(' '))
      testDict[line[0]] = list(line[1:])

print testDict # -> {1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6], 5: [7]}
```